# Get Attribute type of a model in Django

Tags: python, django

Folks, I'm trying to get the type of the Model's attribute. For example, consider the following model below:

```
class Option(models.Model):
  option_text  = models.CharField(max_length=400)
  option_num   = models.IntegerField()
  # add field to hold image or a image url in future

  def __unicode__(self):
        return self.option_text
```

I'm setting each of the attribute of this model programmatically. I need to access the type of the attribute. For example, for option_num,  I should be able to get "IntegerField" or an equivalent.

I saw the meta api, and read the source, too. But I don't see a way to retrieve the internal type.

```
model._meta.get_field(attr_value).getInternalType() => gives me an error.
```

Getting an "'CharField' object has no attribute 'get Internal Type'".

To clarify a little, the reason I need to know whether an attribute is a string or an int is because, if from the front end, I get a string, which is actually an integer, i would like to typecast it.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting? Also please include the actual line you tried without variables

Comment: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'get Internal Type'

Comment: try type(model._meta.get_field(attr_value)). Your error message tells me that you called the method on an object of type CharField and since this is what you wanted, you can get an object's type/class using the type keyword

Comment: type gives me <class 'django.db.models.fields.TextField'>.

Comment: If you're getting this for option_text than this is possible. Depending on your max_length Django might decide to change the charfield to a textfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is use

```
model._meta.get_field(attr_name).get_internal_type()
```

instead of

```
model._meta.get_field(attr_value).getInternalType()
```

Answer (score 5):

you are close with the meta option but you need to remember some Python PEP8 Love.

if you have a model like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  code = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=96)
...
...
```

you can get the type name with:

```
Client._meta.get_field('code').get_internal_type()
u'IntegerField'
```

or you can get the type with:

```
type(Client._meta.get_field('name'))
django.db.models.fields.CharField
```

directly like a Class method, not only from the class instance.
your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get the same **before** initialization of Client(). Because theoretically, I know the types. Is that possible?

Comment: corrected in answer, you can get the _meta fields from Class, not only from class instance